# react typescript: how to change list of child states from parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state, react-tsx

Im using react with typescript. I am a little confused as to how can i pass 'global' parent state to list of its childrens?
For example there is 'Parent' and list of 'Child' components, i want to change parent state and set it to its child components:

```js
interface ParentProps {
    childs: ChildProps[]
}

interface ChildProps {
    isOpen: boolean
}


const ParentComponent: FC<ParentProps> = (parentProps: ParentProps) => {

    const [globalState, setGlobalState] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setOpenState(!changeOpenChildsState);
        // So here i should something like iterate over all childrens and change its state but how ?
    }

    return (
        <>
        <button onClick= { handleClick } />

        parentProps.childs.map(child => {
            <Child isOpen={ child.isOpen } />
        })
        </>
    )
}

const Child: FC<ChildProps> = (childProps: ChildProps) => {

    const [openState, setOpenState] = useState(childProps.isOpen);

    const handleChildClick = () => {
        setOpenState(!openState);
    }

    return (
        <div>
             <button onClick= { handleChildClick } />
             <div> is child open ? { openState } </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to have a "toggle all" button, you can just use `useEffect` and toggle all of the children to the global value when the global state is passed as a prop:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [globalState, setGlobalState] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setGlobalState(prev => !prev);
  }
  
  return (
    <main>
      <button className="set-all" onClick={handleClick}>Set All</button>
      {[1,2,3,4,5].map((_,i) => (
        <Child key={i} isOpen={globalState} />
      ))}
    </main>
  )
}

const Child = ({ isOpen }) => {
  const [openState, setOpenState] = React.useState(isOpen);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpenState(prev => !prev);
  }
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setOpenState(isOpen)
  }, [isOpen])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={ handleClick }>Toggle State</button>
      <p>Is child open ? { openState ? 'yes' : 'no'}</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(<Parent/>)
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  gap: .5rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.set-all {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want to do. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Without using `useContext` and `useReducer` to create state management in your application, maybe something like this could work where you populate a reference on your parent with the functions you need to call. When each of the child components mounts, it passes its setter function to its parent:

```
type ChildFns =  React.MutableRefObject<any[] | undefined>;

interface ParentProps {
  childs: ChildProps[]
}

interface ChildProps {
  isOpen: boolean
  childFn: ChildFns,
}

function ParentComponent(parentProps: ParentProps) {

  const [globalState, setGlobalState] = useState(false);
  const childFns = useRef([]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // set all child booleans to false
    childFns.current.forEach((childFn) => childFn(false));
  }

  return (
      <>
      <button onClick= { handleClick } />

      { parentProps.childs.map((child, i) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
          return <Child isOpen={ child.isOpen } childFn={childFns}/>
      }) }
      </>
  )
}
```

```
function Child(childProps: ChildProps) {

  const [openState, setOpenState] = useState(childProps.isOpen);

  const handleChildClick = () => {
      setOpenState(!openState);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    childProps.childFn.current?.push(setOpenState);
  }, [])

  return (
      <div>
           <button onClick= { handleChildClick } />
           <div> is child open ? { openState } </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```